Is there a name for someone who always talks about their bodily functions?
I know someone who is always talking about when they poop. They have no problems talking about when they have diarrhea, when they have accidents, or when they soil their underwear. And it almost seems like they enjoy sharing this graphic information. They have no filter regarding what to share and what not to share. They are totally comfortable sharing what I think most people would find private.

It sounds like your acquaintance is acting coarse (definition #3) https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/coarse and boorish https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/boorish

There are some reasons to ask about such functions. They are described below.

scatological as in "Sam's conversations are scatological in nature”

Oversharer comes to mind as a single word but it could be too general. Does it have to involve bodily functions only? Or do they overshare any info about their personal life? Perhaps you can clarify and provide an example sentence.

That person is suffering from what today is called: a lack of boundaries

Tourette's Syndrome (or Tourette Syndrome) is not equivalent to having a potty mouth. It's a neurological disorder with a lot of symptoms mainly involving many sorts of physical and verbal tics.

They may be called (from Merriam-Webster)

vulgar
1a: lacking in cultivation, perception, or taste : coarse

which links to

coarse
3: crude or unrefined in taste, manners, or language



coprophiliac Collins Dictionary
[someone who shows a] marked interest in excrement
...she was a total coprophiliac. She loved to talk about bowels — her bowels, my bowels, the dog's bowels. The Nostalgist Griffin Hansbury, 2012

I'm a bit surprised Google reports No results found for "Coprophiliacs talk shit". I was half expecting to find T-shirts printed with that on Amazon!

EDIT: I don't understand the silent downvotes, but I'm guessing this alternative with much the same meaning won't be any better received...

scatological Cambridge Dictionary
relating to solid human waste
I developed a scatological sense of humour: everything to do with farting, shitting, peeing, still makes me laugh Some Sort of a Life Miriam Karlin,  2014

